# Wordpress force scripts to load after plugins

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins

I have a custom js file as part of my wordpress installation, which is registered and enqueued using functions.php as normal. I have registered this particular script to load within wp_footer rather than within wp_header. However, I also have a plugin that is putting js into wp_footer, and by default it is loading this below my script. I need to force my script to load last. Is there soemthing simple that can be done to achieve this? It seems like something fairly routine to me?

Here is my code:

```
function scripts() {
// Register scripts
// js
wp_register_script('custom', get_bloginfo('template_url'). '/js/custom.js', false, false, true);

// Enqueue scripts
wp_enqueue_script('custom');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'scripts');
```

The current order of the scripts goes, but I need to force my script to load after the plugin:

```
<script>/my_script.js</script>
<script>/plugin_script.js</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  I have the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Just set the `$priority` parameter to a ridiculously high value:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'scripts', 999999 );
```

To be the very last in the queue (though one can never be sure) use [php's `PHP_INT_MAX` constant](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php):

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'scripts', PHP_INT_MAX );
```

**Edit** cf. discussion in comments. Note that the following is **NOT** the recommended way of enqueueing scripts in the footer.

```
add_action( 'wp_print_footer_scripts', 'so26898556_print_footer_scripts', ( PHP_INT_MAX - 2 ) );
function so26898556_print_footer_scripts()
{
    echo '<script src="' . get_bloginfo( 'template_url' ) . '/js/custom.js"></script>';
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately neither of these work? I had tried the high priority number after reading the codex but not the PHP, but tried that too and nothing?

Comment: Could you check that plugin's source code to see how the script included is enqueued?

Comment: This looks suspect to me? However, I don't really want to edit the plugin files as upgrades will overwrite, however maybe we can decifer a workaround from this?

Comment: function custom_footer_scripts($init_codes = null) {
  if(!$init_codes) {
   $init_codes = NewRoyalSliderMain::$sliders_init_code;
  }
  
  if(count($init_codes) > 0 ) {
   echo "<script id=\"new-royalslider-init-code\" type=\"text/javascript\">\n";
   echo "jQuery(document).ready(function($) {\n";
   foreach($init_codes  as $key => $value) {
    echo $value;
   }
   do_action( 'new_rs_after_js_init_code', $init_codes);
   echo "});\n";
   echo "</script>\n";
  }
 }

Comment: You should check to what `custom_footer_scripts` is hooked. Possibly `wp_print_scripts` or `wp_footer`? I'm afraid you'll have to use the same hook as the plugin for your script, and set the priority to a higher number.

Comment: The only other thing I can find from your advice is the following: add_action( 'wp_print_footer_scripts', array( &$this, 'custom_footer_scripts' ) );

I believe this is what you were referring to although I have tried to implement to my own script and I cannot seem to get it to work. Is there any chance you could amend the code originally provided to attempt your proposed solution?

It would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this worked for me, one thing I changed is the priority from 999999 to 20